# ionic 3 HttpClient get status + send headers

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-httpclient

i'm using the HttpClientModule on ionic 3, and i want to do a get on my api

```
let email = "test@email.com";
let password = "password";
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login',{
      headers: {'email':email,'password':password}
   });
```

i don't want to get the json but only the status of the request, for doing something like :

```
if(status == 200) { ... }
esle { ... }
```

can you guys please help me ?

Thank you

Comment: See: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **observe : 'response'** in header options of http.get method and **subscribe** to get() method to get response status whatever you want..

```
this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login',{
      headers: {'email':email,'password':password},observe: 'response'
   }).subscribe(
    res => { console.log(res) ;

             if(res.status==201)
             {
                 //do action
             }else
             {
             }
          },
```

Comment: it's not working, i'm on ionic 3, it's problably the main reason

I got this on my console : 
`- OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login 403 (Forbidden)

- Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403. `

Comment: ok sorry, the code is working, the error come from this line : 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: the code is probably working, but my ionic is on the port 8100 , and my api is on the port 8000, so i have the error :  `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. `

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `observe: 'response'` as you second parameter in the Get request of httpClientModule like this -

```
this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login',{
      headers: {'email':email,'password':password},
      observe: 'response'
   }
```

> observe : '**response**' for complete response.
>
> observe : '**body**' for response with body.
>
> observe : '**events**' for response with events. 
>   For more details on this refer here

- https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-httpclient-get-example#observe

Comment: thank you for the response, but it's not working for me, my code is :

    `this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login',{
      headers: {email:'leo.chenet@hotmail.fr',password :'chenet'},
      observe: 'response'
   }).subscribe(
    response => { 
     console.log(response);
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
`
but this return an error.. On postman, i can doing my request get, send the headers, and i got a 200 status, 
i just want get the status after the get