# How can we get HttpClient Status Code in Angular 4

Tags: angular

Hi new for Angular and i am facing problem for getting HTTP status code that is In HTTP Module I can easily get the response code using **response.status**, but when I used `HttpClient` Module I can not get the response.status, it shows can not find status.

So, how can I get the response.status using `HttpClient` module in `Angular 4&5`. Please help.

### RestProvider:-

```
@Injectable()
export class RestProvider {

  private apiUrl = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/al';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello RestProvider Provider');
  }

  getCountries(): Observable<{}> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl).pipe(
      map(this.extractData),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res;
    return body || { };
  }

  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const err = error || '';
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

}
```

### HomePage:

```
export class HomePage {

  responseStatus: number;

  countries: any;
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public rest: RestProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.getCountries();
  }

  getCountries() {
    this.rest.getCountries().subscribe(res =>{
      this.countries=res;
      console("status code--->"+res.status)
    },
    err=>{
      console("status code--->"+err.status)
    })

  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Add **`observe : 'response'`** in header options of `http.get` method like

```
getCountries(): Observable<{}> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl,{observe : 'response'}).pipe(
      map(this.extractData),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

and subscribe to get() method to get response status whatever you want in your HomePage like you have done

```
 getCountries() {
this.rest.getCountries().subscribe(
    res => {  this.countries=res;
  console("status code--->"+res.status)
},
err=>{
  console("status code--->"+err.status)
})
          },
```

Answer (score 9):

To get full response you need to add extra property to response which is `observe` like this -

```
getCountries(): Observable<{}> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, {observe: 'response'}).pipe(
      map(this.extractData),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

For more information you can refer -

- https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response
- [HttpClient get status + send headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50592180/5043867)

Comment: this.http.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all',{
          observe: 'response'}).subscribe(res => {
          this.countries=res;
        },err=>{
          
        });

Comment: as you said i wrote code above but atlease response also not coming now

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Angular's interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) to catch all the errors in one place and keep your services neat. Create a new interceptor called "error-interceptor" and add the intercept method:

```
  intercept(request, next) {
    // Handle response
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        //handle specific errors
        if (error.status === 401) {
          this.handle401();
        }

        //default case: print, log, toast, etc...
        return throwError(error.message || error);
      })
    );
  }
```