# How to get statusCode in angular

Tags: angular, httprequest, angular15

How can I make a method that return the status Code of the request?

I'm using angular 15.

My get method in service:

```
public getData( ano: any, mes: any, glosadas: any, pagina:any): Observable<any> {
const token = this.token.retornaToken();
const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` });

return this.http.get(`API/?TpoRelatorio=1
&SomenteGlosadas=${glosadas}
&Ano=${ano}
&Mes=${mes}
&Page=${pagina}
&Count=0`,{ headers }
)
```

}

I want the status code for this method in component.ts

```
todasGuias() {
this.paginaBusca = 1;
while (this.paginaBusca <= this.listaGuias.TotalPages) {
  this.homeService
    .getData( this.ano, this.mes, this.glosadas, this.paginaBusca)
    .subscribe((data) => {
      if (data.status == 200) {
        this.listaGuias = data.Dados[0];
        this.listaTodasGuias.push(this.listaGuias.ResultList);
        console.log(this.listaGuias);
        console.log(this.listaTodasGuias);
        var options = {
          fieldSeparator: ',',
          quoteStrings: '"',
          decimalseparator: '.',
          showLabels: true,
          showTitle: true,
          title: 'Consulta',
          useBom: true,
          headers: [ 'Guia', 'Tipo', 'Protocolo', 'Valor Informado', 'Valor Total', 'Cliente' ],
        };

        new ngxCsv(this.listaTodasGuias, 'Consulta', options);
      }
    });
  this.paginaBusca++;
}
```

I don't know if it's rigth, just looking for some help!

Comment: Like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/50929021/9590251

Comment: But when I add  `{oberseve:'response'}`  it says: "the method just expected 1-2 arguments", and I can't take off the header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `observe: 'response'` option in the http request inside your getData method:

```
public getData( ano: any, mes: any, glosadas: any, pagina:any): Observable<any> {
    const token = this.token.retornaToken();
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` });

    return this.http.get(`API/?TpoRelatorio=1
        &SomenteGlosadas=${glosadas}
        &Ano=${ano}
        &Mes=${mes}
        &Page=${pagina}
        &Count=0`,
        { headers, observe: 'response' }
    )
}
```

This way you'll get the complete response back.

In your components subscription you can access the HTTP status code with `data.status` and the http response body with `data.body`:

```js
 this.homeService
    .getData( this.ano, this.mes, this.glosadas, this.paginaBusca)
    .subscribe(data => {
        if (data.status === 200) {
            this.listaGuias = data.body.Dados[0];
        }
    })
```